# At most one record can be returned by this subquery

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I am facing this error in my SQL select query. How can I fix this?

When I run this query and if there is only one record in `HR_info` table regarding my query then it show that result in combo box. If there are more than one record in this table then it show this error.

```
sSQL1 = "SELECT HR_Info.HR_ID, 
            (select hotel_name from hotel_info 
             where hotel_id = (select hotel_id 
                               from hr_info 
                               where hr_info.group_id = forms!pasenger_detail!group_id)) 
         FROM HR_Info 
         WHERE (((HR_Info.Group_ID) = [forms]![Pasenger_Detail]![Group_ID]));"
```

here is the hotel_info talbe data
[image]

here is the hr_info table data
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try TOP 1 or MAX / MIN on your sub subquery

Comment: because this is the best guess we can actually make with the information you have provided. Please share the error message and a little more insight would help us to understand the issue better and then suggest a solution.

Comment: sir it work for me, first of thanks. but here i have a new problem now. the problem is it is giving me hr_id according to the criteria but it giving me false result for hotel name. its assigning hotel name of first hotel to all hr_id fields but it wrong.

Comment: sSQL1 = "SELECT HR_Info.HR_ID, (select hotel_name from hotel_info where hotel_id = (select TOP 1 hotel_id from hr_info where hr_info.group_id=forms!pasenger_detail!group_id)) FROM HR_Info WHERE (((HR_Info.Group_ID)=[forms]![Pasenger_Detail]![Group_ID]));"                   This is the changed query.

Comment: I'm not really know what you want, if you want get all HR_ID and hotel_name by a special group, You just need join HR_Info and hotel_info by hotel_id.